# Process.on(unhandledRejection) log the actual promise instead of [Object Promise]

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, error-logging, unhandled-promise-rejection

I feel there should be an easy answer to this I am missing. I rarely get unhandledRejections, however when I do, the `reason` from `process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {...`is not always enough to find the origination of the error. So I was hoping to also log information on the `[Object Promise]` that gets logged from `promise`.

Code:

```js
module.exports = async (client, process, reason, promise) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const formatDate = stripIndents`${(date.getMonth() + 1)
        .toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${date.getDate()
            .toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${date.getFullYear()
                .toString().padStart(4, '0')}`

    const formatTime = stripIndents`${date.getHours()
        .toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${date.getMinutes()
            .toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${date.getSeconds()
                .toString().padStart(2, '0')}`

    var dir = './logs';

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) fs.mkdirSync(dir);

    fs.appendFile(`./logs/${formatDate} UnhandledRejection.log`, `${formatDate} ${formatTime}: A new unhandledRejection: at promise ${promise} for: ${reason}\n`, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`A new UnhandledRejection has been logged to: ${formatDate} UnhandledRejection.log`)
    });
}
```

This of course logs something similar to this in my log file:

09-28-2021 04-00-15: A new unhandledRejection error [object Promise] for TypeError: Volume must be a number.
Which in this case, I know I am referring to my volume for my music player, but when I get something like this:

`08-10-2021 07-03-02: A new unhandledRejection error [object Promise] for TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters`, it can be very hard to find where this problem is coming from.

Although the `reason` is usually enough to find the origination of the error, gaining access to the `[Object Promise]`, could help further pinpoint the error. I have tried `promise.catch(...)`, `promise.then(...)`, `promise.then(...).catch(...)`, all of which resulted in an infinite console logging loop.